# OCaml: How to test scanner and parser?

Tags: parsing, ocaml

We are writing a compiler in OCaml for our own domain specific language. So far, we have working scanner, parser and ast.

What is the best way to test scanner/parser at this point? I know it is possible to pass a sequence of tokens to the parser/scanner and see if it gets accepted/rejected by the scanner/parser. (such as, `echo "FLOAT ID" | menhir --interpret --interpret-show-cst parser.mly`).
But, is there a way to pass the actual program written in our own language to the scanner/parser and see whether it gets accepted?

I have to add that I am very new to OCaml and I know very little about compilers.

Comment: Can't you use Lexing.from_channel or Lexing.from_string ?

_val from_string : string -> lexbuf

Create a lexer buffer which reads from the given string. Reading starts from the first character in the string. An end-of-input condition is generated when the end of the string is reached._

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want to do is to give a string to your parser and see if it works, you could do this (supposing your starting point in the parser is *prog*)

```
 main.ml :
 let () = 
    (* Taking the string given as a parameter or the program *)
    let lb = Lexing.from_string Sys.argv.(1) in
    (* if you want to parse a file you should write :
       let ci = open_in filename in
       let lb = Lexing.from_channel ci in
    *)
    try
       let p = Parser.prog Lexer.token lb in
       Printf.printf "OK\n"
    with _ -> Printf.printf "Not OK\n"
```

Did I help ? ;-)

Comment: Yes, this is very helpful. Thanks. It gives me a warning that variable 'p' is not used anywhere.

Comment: Yes, that's because I don't know what you want to do with it. If you wrote, in your parser %start <Ast.ast> prog then _p_ will be of type _Ast.ast_ and you do whatever you want to do with it ;-) If you don't want to use it, just write _let _ = Parser.prog Lexer.token lb_ _(don't forget to upvote and accept the answer ;-))_

Comment: What is this variable going to hold?

Comment: The variable is going to hold the ast resulting of your parsing or whatever comes out of you _prog_ rule.

Comment: thank you for your help. how do I upvote and accept the answer?

Comment: I think you found how to accept. To upvote it may be impossible for you since you're new ;-)